# Test Schema in my own gmail id

Tags: google-schemas

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Approve Expense",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://myexpenses.com/approve?expenseId=abc123"
    }
  },
  "description": "Approval request for John's $10.13 expense for office supplies"
}
</script>
```

This is a sample schema I copied from the example. I am using gmail html client in chrome to send HTML emails using this tag.
Why doesn't the action show up? I am sending it to my own email and I received the email. But no actions are shown.

Comment: This [Email Markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview) discusses actions in length.

Comment: Read through the whole document. Still don't know why this sample won't work in my gmail account. Will inbox actions not appear in personal gmail accounts? I've seen some of the actions appear in my work gmail. If it is an email from google calendar or from confluence etc.